# Number of rounds for a tournament with n teams and $x$ types of games

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

We have $n$ teams ($n$ is even) and $x<n$ types of games (basketball, volleyball...).

We have $x$ pitches, one for each game (one volleyball pitch, one basketball pitch...).

Each day, every pitch can be used at most once.

In our tournament:

- Every team must play each game exactly once
- No two teams should meet each other more than once

How does the minimum number of days needed $d$ depend on $n$ and $x$?

Many times you can be fully efficient and $d=x$ (such as when $n=6$ and $x=3$), but sometimes $d>x$ (e. g. when $n=4$ and $x=2$, $d=4$).

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to do the tournament with an odd number of teams when each team can only play a given game once. Who pairs up with the last team?

Comment: You're right, silly me. I have changed the question to account for this.